# Python UpSert - not enough arguments

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

This has been a bit frustrating today. I'm sure its something simple that I'm overlooking. See code below (simplified for example sake):

```py
def dbUpsert(sqlQuery, sqlValues):
    # Connect to the database
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='db_user',
                                password='###',
                                db='garden',
                                charset='utf8mb4',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Create a new record
            cursor.execute(sqlQuery, sqlValues)
        # Commit the changes
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()


sqlValues = real_plants, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),  10
print (sqlValues)
##### Output: ('roses', '2020-02-19', 10)

sqlQuery = """
    INSERT INTO summ_plants_day 
        (
            real_plants, d_date, acc_plants
        )
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        real_plants = %s,
        d_date = %s,
        acc_plants = %s
    """
dbUpsert(sqlQuery, sqlValues)
```

In my database, I have 4 columns. One is an auto-increment primary key, `real_plants` and `d_date` together form an index, and `acc_plants` is the value I want to update / insert.

If an entry for `roses` exists in table `summ_plants_day` for the `d_date` I want to `UPDATE`, otherwise I want to `INSERT`.

Here is the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 in dbUpsert
    cursor.execute(sqlQuery, sqlValues)
 in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
 in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Also, I used `%s` based on W3Schools examples. I saw conflicting information online while Googling my issue, is this proper/modern format to protect against SQL injection?

Comment: You have 6 `%s` but `sqlValues` only contains 3 elements.

Comment: Try: `dbUpsert(sqlQuery, sqlValues * 2)`

Comment: So `real_plants = %s,` should actually be `real_plants,`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the `VALUES()` syntax in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. This avoids the need to pass the same variable twice, so it should work just fine with your existing code:

```
INSERT INTO summ_plants_day (real_plants, d_date, acc_plants)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    real_plants = VALUES(real_plants),
    d_date = VALUES(d_date),
    acc_plants = VALUES(acc_plants)
```

Comment: Does this exist in postgres too?

Comment: @roganjosh: no. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEYS` is a MySQL syntax, that is not supported in other databases. Other products might have equivalent syntax (Postgres has `ON CONFLICT`), but the syntax is not the same.

Comment: I thought as much, but I could have been missing a trick :) Thanks

Comment: I'm not the asker (other than the comment)

Comment: Thanks so much. Since it is index based, what if I wanted to only update `acc_plants` `ON DUPLICATE KEY` though, out of curiosity? Is the proper format to use brackets, i.e. `VALUES({0}, {1}, {2})` and `acc_plants = VALUES({2})`? Is it vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @SamiA. If you want to update just one column, then: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    real_plants = VALUES(real_plants)`

Comment: Ok. That question stemmed from a misunderstanding. I thought it was index based on the line that says `VALUES(%s, %s, %s)`. I understand how the parameterization happens now. Thanks so much for sharing the knowledge.